# Cross browser-window events?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

Is it possible to fire events picked up by a separate browser window? With JavaScript perhaps.

i.e. if my website opened up another window to display summary product information, would it be possible to notify that window to update when a different product is selected in the main window?

Needs to work in IE, but doesn't need to work on Chrome or other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a **couple** of options.

1. [Cross-Document-Messaging](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/#web-messaging) allows you to pass events between windows. For this to work, you need to have a handle of the target window, which you can really only acquire if the target is either an `<iframe>` (e.g. through `window.frames`, or `window.parent` from the iframe's POV) or if the target is a window opened by the current window through `window.open()` or `window.opener` from the popup's POV.
2. [Shared Workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html) can connect otherwise unassociated windows much like Cross-Document-Messaging. Shared Workers are [only available in Chrome and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#search=shared%20web%20worker), though.
3. [Server-Sent Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) could use the server to proxy the communication between your otherwise unassociated windows. This reqires a round-trip to the server (so is not entirely client-based) and is [not available in Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource).
4. [Web Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/) are an option, too. They too suffer from a server round trip and are [not available in Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20socket). There is [socket.io](http://socket.io/), which polyfills this functionality down to old Internet Explorers - so might be a viable solution.
5. A hacky solution is [abusing LocalStorage](http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyrehm/bAhJL/). It'll work in modern Browsers and IE8.
6. [jQuery BrowserEvent](https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-browserEvent/) was something I played with way back when. It abuses the `window.event` and browsers' local storage capabilites to simulate passing events between browsers. This is nothing you'd want to use in a production environment, though.

---

German fellows may want to check out [Kommunikations-APIs in HTML5 - Welche wann nutzen?](http://www.peterkroener.de/echtzeit-kommunikations-apis-in-html5-welche-wann-nutzen/)

Comment: You forgot "Write an ActiveX control and use traditional native IPC."  Though, maybe you did that on purpose.  :)

Comment: Great reply, thorough information. Really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use code like this:

**Parent window**

```
var func = function() {...}
child = window.open(...)
```

**Child window**

```
window.opener.func(); // Call function in parent window
```

You can also call function in the child window from the parent but there is one problem: You must wait until the child window has finished loading; `window.open()` is asynchronous.

More details: [Accessing parent window from child window or vice versa using JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25388/Accessing-parent-window-from-child-window-or-vice)

Comment: I'd say `window.opener.closed || window.opener.func();` to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that would be possible **if** the window with product information would be open using window.open method in parent window.

That way you can induce communication between those two (without, strictly speaking, events) but with some extra code that's possible.